# Como colocar o número da última linha de uma tabela MySQL numa variável

Tags: php, mysql

Gostaria de saber como pegar a última linha de uma tabela MySQL, e colocar este número dentro de uma variável PHP.

Tentei assim:

```
require_once "../../models/conex.php";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tabela ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
$ultimaLinha = $query;
$mysqli->close();
```

Mas o `var_dump` retorna `boolean false`...

Comment: Você está fechando a conexão antes de pegar o resultado, faltou o `fetch()`. Ou sua consulta real tem algum erro, pq a ideia é essa mesma ordenar por id de forma decrescente e retorna uma linha.

Comment: Não esqueça de ver se exise algum erro na consula `$query = $db->query($sql) or die($db->error);`

Comment: @rray, `$db` no caso é o link de conexão? no meu caso `$mysqli`?

Comment: @rray além de esquecer do `fetch`, tinha um erro na consulta mesmo, tava passando o nome do campo errado. Depois que coloquei o  `$query = $mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error);`que vc sugeriu, apareceu o erro `Unknown column 'id' in 'order clause'` e aí bingo.... Ficou assim:
`require_once "../../models/conex.php";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tabela ORDER BY idcerto DESC LIMIT 1";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error); while ($dados = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    print_r($dados['idcerto']);
}`

Comment: Cria uma resposta,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Só pra constar, o problema era que, além de esquecer do `fetch` (o que foi  apontado pelo @rray), também tinha um erro na consulta, pois estava passando o nome do campo errado.

Depois que coloquei o

```
$query = $mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error);
```

por sugestão do @rray, apareceu o erro:

> Unknown column 'id' in 'order clause'

<s>Então foi apenas incluir o `while` com o `fetch`, e corrigir o nome do campo.</s>

Ficou assim:

```
require_once "../../models/conex.php";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tabela ORDER BY idcerto DESC LIMIT 1"; 
$query =    $mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error); 
while ($dados = $query->fetch_assoc()) { 
print_r($dados['idcerto']); 
}
```

> UPDATE

Seguindo a orientação do @DanielOmine nos comentários, troquei o `while` pelo `if`, por duas razões:

- como só vai retornar um resultado, não precisa do `while`;
- colocando o `if` ele verifica se o resultado não retorna vazio;

O código normalizado:

```
    require_once "../../models/conex.php";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tabela ORDER BY idcerto DESC LIMIT 1"; 
    $query =    $mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error); 

    if ($dados = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $idcerto = (int)(($dados['idcalc']) + 1);
        echo $idcerto;
    }
    else{

        echo "erro na obtenção da id";

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: não precisa do laço de repetição pois retornará apenas um resultado.

Comment: @DanielOmine trocando por um `if` funcionou tbm... é mais correto assim, por ele fazer uma verificação (se `$query->fetch_assoc()` for true...), ou passando assim é melhor: `$idcerto = NULL;
    $dados = $query->fetch_assoc();
    $idcerto = (int)(($dados['idcalc']) + 1);
        echo $idcerto;` (funciona tbm) Não rola uma resposta?

Comment: isso! coloca um if() pois também pode vir vazio.
`if ($dados = $query->fetch_assoc()){print_r($dados);}else{echo 'vazio';}`

Comment: Legal, se animar faz uma resposta... valeu! @DanielOmine

Comment: é que fica sem sentido responder. Edite a sua resposta com o if(), removendo o while()  aí fica manero!

Comment: Ok Valeu! Só mais uma dúvida, eu declaro a variável direto dentro do if, ou declaro depois faço o if, assim: `$dados = $query->fetch_assoc();
    if ($dados = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $idcerto = (int)(($dados['idcalc']) + 1);}`? @DanielOmine

Comment: pode ser dentro do if(). `if ($dados = $query->fetch_assoc())`

Answer (score 3):

Implemente desta forma e não esqueça de recuperar o erro, pode estar havendo alguma exceção e você não está recuperando.

Tente isso:

```
$leitura = "SELECT * FROM php_teste"; <== seu select
$resultado =mysqli_query($leitura) or die (mysqli_error());
if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) <=0){
    echo 'não tem nada';
} else {
    while($mostra = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        print_r($mostra);
    }
}
```

Comment: Então, não funcionou... pelo que vi aqui o `mysqli_query` pede também o link de conexão como parâmetro, e o `mysql_error` pede a variável da `query`... e no `while` acho que seria `while($mostra = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado))` né (está `$query`)...  mas mesmo colocando `mysqli_query($conn, $leitura) or die (mysqli_error($leitura));`, e mudando o `while` não funcionou, e não aparece nenhum erro... Até acho que é algum erro bobo que to cometendo aqui... +1 pela força... abraço.

Comment: Faça o seguinte abra o phpAdmin e execute esta query diretamente nele, certifique-se que existam dados. Já aconteceu comigo e não vir o resultado e o problema era simples, não tinha mesmo resultado. Faça isso.... sucesso

Answer (score 1):

Coloque:

```
$linha = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$variavel=$linha["NOME DA COLUNA DESEJADA"];
```